# Como utilizar corretamente o Chooser do Android através de um plugin customizado para o Capacitor?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ionic

Estou tentando desenvolver um File Chooser para um aplicativo desenvolvido em Ionic, a intenção dessa função é para poder ler grandes arquivos. Eu tentei utilizar o [plugin do Capacitor](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/Chooser), porém o aplicativo quebra(crash) com arquivos acima de 25 mb, dependendo do celular. Através do Memory Profiler descobri que é por conta do alto uso de memória do Chooser ao selecionar um arquivo, diante disso estou tentando criar o meu próprio Chooser para controlar o uso de memória.

Estou usando o próprio Capacitor para criar [plugins personalizados](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/android).

Iniciei meu desenvolvimento com alguns exemplos que encontrei no [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856959/android-file-chooser), a partir disso comecei a ter alguns erros na função `startActivityForResult()`. A partir a documentação do [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) eu tentei criar novas Activties e obter suas respostas. Foi possível validar que o código desenvolvido funciona pois a função `startActivity()` abriu o File Chooser como esperado, mas eu preciso obter a Uri do arquivo. Com a função `startActivityForResult()` não consigo nem abrir o File Chooser.

Mesmo criando uma nova Activity ainda ocorria um erro no [Lifecycle da Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). O erro era algo [parecido com isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748248/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-app-ac). Reescrevi meu código baseado na [documentação do Android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) sobre Intents. Usando tudo que tinha reunido meu, código ficou assim:

```
public class ReadFile extends Activity {
    public void openFile(String mimetype) {
        try {
          mGetContent.launch(mimeType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
      new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
          System.out.println("uri " + uri);
        }
    }); 
}
```

A IDE me dizia que a função `registerForActivityResult()` não existia em minha classe, então achei uma [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72026607/13313703) que acabou me ajudando no meu problema. Resolvi esse problema instanciando um novo [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) em minha classe.

```
public class ReadFile extends Activity {

    private Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

    public void openFile(String mimetype) {
        try {
          mGetContent.launch(mimeType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = fragment.registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
      new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
          System.out.println("uri " + uri);
        }
    });

}
```

Outro erro apareceu, mais especificamente este: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Operation cannot be started before fragment is in created state`. Achei uma discussão interessante em um [fórum da Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161464278). Li a documentação do [Lifecycle do Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle) e tentei aplicar os seus métodos.

```
private MyLocationListener myLocationListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(...) {
    myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener(this, (location) -> {
        // update UI
    });
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    myLocationListener.start();
    // manage other components that need to respond
    // to the activity lifecycle
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    myLocationListener.stop();
    // manage other components that need to respond
    // to the activity lifecycle
}
```

Mesmo aplicando esses métodos do Lifecycle não consegui fazer com que o File Chooser funcionasse. Meu objetivo é conseguir obter os dados do arquivo selecionado através do Chooser.